# Checking if a value is a decimal in an input

Tags: stored-procedures, sqlanywhere

I'm learning SQL using SQLAnywhere which I believe uses a fairly standard SQL syntax

My problem is I have created a table MatchRecord with an Id as char(4) NOT NULL, a score as decimal and a pins as decimal.

now I want to create a procedure insert_scores to insert values into the table
I have got so far as :

```
    create procedure insert_scores(IN play_id char(4), IN play_score decimal(5, 2), 
    IN no_pins decimal(5, 2), OUT a_message varchar(40))

    begin
    if substr(play_id, 1, 1)in (Upper('M','F', 'J'
    then
       if isnumeric(substr(play_id 2, 3)) = 1
       then
          if isnumeric(play_score) = 1
          then
             if isnumeric(no_pins) = 1
             then 
               insert into MatchRecord(id, score, pins)
               values(play_id, play_score, no_pins);
               set a_message = 'Entry successful';
             else
             set a_message = 'Number of pins must be decimal ie, 1.6 ';
             end if;
            else
            set a_message = 'Score must be decimal ie, 9.4 ';
            end if;
         else
         set a_message = 'ID number must be in range 000 to 999 ';
         end if;
   else
   set a_message = 'First character of ID must be M, F of J':
   end if;
```

end

this works fine apart for any accidental insertion of a character in either of the decimal values, whereupon the system throws an error, it seems to check the table type before it reads the if statement,
I have tried isnumeric(string(play_score)) = 1 but still the same error.

Is there any way of checking that the number passed in play_score and no_pins is a decimal before the first if statement?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to transform your number into a string and then check if there is a dot in the string. Something like this could do the trick.

```
DECLARE @number_is_ok BIT

SET @number_is_ok = CASE charindex('.', CAST(play_score as CHAR))
       WHEN 0 THEN 0
       ELSE 1
       END
```

You could do then a simple check if the number is decimal or not and then continue with the corresponding logic.

```
IF @number_is_ok = 1 ...
```

Comment: Thanks Radu, but if the input is 2a.5 it will still fail.

Comment: You didn't specify a case like that. You should remove letters and other characters from within your application. Or do you want to keep it strictly to SQL?

Comment: Trying to keep it strictly SQL. I tried to check against SQLSTATE but it doesn't accept that so I tried catching an exception but it won't do that either.

Comment: It would complicate the SQL part quite a lot in order to take account for every possible situations when parsing your input. Is there no way you can accomplish this in your business layer?

Comment: As yet there is no business layer, just trying to catch any possible improper input and make it as foolproof as possible.